# Redirect with state values in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

H i everyone.

I have a 2nd hand market makes with react and react-redux.
In the main page, you can choose the category of the products that you want to see.

```
import { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { obtenerProductosAction } from "../actions/productoActions";
import Producto from "./Producto";
import PaginasBtn from "./PaginasBtn";

const Productos = (props) => {

  //const {busqueda} = (props.location && props.location.state)
  const productos = useSelector((state) => state.productos.productos);
  const paginasTotales = useSelector((state) => state.productos.paginas);
  const paginas = new Array(paginasTotales).fill(null).map((v, i) => i);

  const [busqueda, setBusqueda] = useState('all'); //SELECCION DE CATEGORIA DE PRODUCTOS A MOSTRAR  
  
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState();

  //PARA PODER RECIBIR DEL COMPONENTE PAGINASBTN LOS VALORES DE LOS NUM Y EL CAMBIO (ES EL CHILD)
  const envioPagina = (pagina) => {
    console.log(pagina);
    setPageNumber(pagina);
  };

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const cargarProductos = (busqueda, pageNumber) =>
    dispatch(obtenerProductosAction(busqueda, pageNumber));
  //  const busquedaStore = window.localStorage.getItem('valorBusqueda')
  
  useEffect(() => {        
   
    cargarProductos(busqueda, pageNumber);
    console.log("vuelvo a llar a la api");
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [busqueda, pageNumber ]);

  console.log(pageNumber);
  
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div
        className="container-fluid  my-2 p-1 mt-4"
        style={{ position: "relative" }}
      >
        <div>
          {/* <h2 className="text-center">ENCUENTRA LO QUE ESTÁS BUSCANDO</h2> */}
          <div className=" mb-3 col-6 mx-auto">
            <form>
              <div className="container d-flex ">
                <select
                  className="form-select col-6"
                  defaultValue={busqueda}
                  name="categoria"
                  //value={busqueda}
                  onChange={(e) => setBusqueda(e.target.value)}
                >
                  {/* <option value="" selected>
                  Selecciona el tipo de producto
                </option> */}
                <option value="">Selecciona los productos</option>
                  <option value="all">Ver Últimos los Productos</option>
                  <option value="tabla">Tabla</option>
                  <option value="vela">Vela</option>
                  <option value="botavara">Botavara</option>
                  <option value="mastil">Mastil</option>
                  <option value="accesorio">Accesorio</option>
                </select>
                {/* <button className="btn btn-outline-primary text-center ms-2">
                  Buscar
                </button> */}
              </div>
            </form>
            <div>
              <h2 className="mt-5 text-center">Categoria: {busqueda}</h2>
            </div>
            {/* <label className="mb-2">Selecciona el tipo de producto</label> */}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className=" row row-cols-2 row-cols-xs-2 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-lg-4 g-3 ">
          {productos === undefined
            ? null
            : productos.map((producto, busqueda) => (
                <Producto key={producto._id} producto={producto} busqueda={busqueda}/>
              ))}
        </div>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-4 ">
          {paginas.map((pagina) => (
            <PaginasBtn
              key={pagina}
              paginaS={pagina}
              envioPagina={envioPagina}
            />
            
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Productos;
```

This load the products and the pagination from the API.

Then i can see the products individually:

**Product.js component:**

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import "./Producto.css";
//import './ProductoUser.css'
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
//import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
//REDUX
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { obtenerProductoIdAction } from "../actions/productoActions";
//import { obtenerProductoVisionar } from "../actions/productoActions";

const Producto = ({ producto }) => {
  //LOD PRODUCTOS LLEGAN POR PROPS DE PRODUCTOS.JS
  //const { user: currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  //console.log(producto._id)
  const { title, price, images } = producto;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  // console.log(currentUser)

  const verProductoId = (producto ) => {
    dispatch(obtenerProductoIdAction(producto));
    console.log(producto);

    history.push(`/productos/${producto._id}`);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="col">
        <div className="card shadow-sm gap-2  me-0">
          <div className="">
            <img
              src={images[0].url}
              className="card-img-top"
              alt={images[0].filename}
            ></img>
          </div>
          <div className="card-body text-center">
            <h5 className="price-hp">{price}€</h5>
            <h5 className="titleH5 card-title text-center">{title}</h5>
            <button
              className="btn btn-outline-primary mt-2 mb-1" 
              onClick={() => verProductoId(producto) }
            >
              Ver Producto
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
      <div className="card mb-2 ">
        <div className="card-header text-center">
          <h5 className='display-7'>{title}</h5>
        </div>        
        <img
            className="image-fluid m-3"
            style={{ height: '100px', objectFit: 'cover'}}
            src={images[0].url}
            alt="imagen nula"
          ></img>
        <div className="card-body text-center bg-light">
          <p style={{ color: "red" }}>Precio: {price}€</p>
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary"
            onClick={() => verProductoId(producto)}
          >
            Ver Producto
          </button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div> */}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Producto;
```

And after see the full product,
VerProducto.js :

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link,  Redirect, useLocation, useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import "./VerProducto.css";

const VerProducto = () => {
 
  const location = useLocation()
  const history = useHistory();
  
  const producto = useSelector((state) => state.productos.productoId);
  console.log(producto);

  if (!producto) {
    return null;
  }
  const { title, price, description, images, contacto } = producto;
  
  
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="col">
        <div className="card1 h-100 mt-5">
          <a href={images[0].url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
            <img
              src={images[0].url}
              className="card-img-top1 mt-3"
              alt={images[0].filename}
            ></img>
          </a>
          <div className="card-body">
            <div className="clearfix mb-3 text-center">
              <span className=" price-hp1">Precio: {price} €</span>
            </div>
            <h5 className="card-title titleH5V rounded text-center">{title}</h5>
            <div className="card-header mb-2">
              <span className="card-title pproducto text-center">Descripción:</span>
              <p className="card-title pproducto">{description}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="card-header">
              <span className="card-title  pproducto text-center">Contacto:</span>
              <p className="card-title pproducto ">{contacto}</p>
            </div>
            <button className= 'btn btn-info' onClick={(e)=>history.push({pathname:'/productos', state: {busqueda: 'vela'}})}>Volver a productos</button>

             <div className="text-center my-4">
              <Link to={{pathname: '/productos/'}} className="btn btn btn-info">
                VOLVER A PRODUCTOS
              </Link>
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default VerProducto;
```

When i use one of this options (Link or history) i try to return to the same page that i was and in the same category. (i think when i will be in page(55) and want to return at same page to see other full product.

But the app return to the main page and to the default category....

Someone can show me a light to continue....Thanks!!!

Comment: what about set the filter on your global state (redux) and get it when user load the page ?
Another option is to pass some query params on url that set the filter and page, up to you

Comment: Than @barden, maybe i am in a low level of you in react, because i know how to pass a query param, but how can i pass to the useState to show the previous page and filter....? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your ideas @barden,
Now it's work for me with these updates in the code.

**Productos.js (component)**

```
import { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  obtenerProductosAction,
  obtenerCategoriaActions,
  obtenerPaginaAction,
} from "../actions/productoActions";
import Producto from "./Producto";
import "./Producto.css";

const Productos = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location);

  const productos = useSelector((state) => state.productos.productos);
  const paginasTotales = useSelector((state) => state.productos.paginas);  
  const errores = useSelector((state)=> state.productos.error401)
  console.log(errores)

  const paginas = new Array(paginasTotales).fill(null).map((v, i) => i);  

  const params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
  let busquedaquery = params.get("busqueda");
  let pagequery = params.get("page");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const cargarProductos = () =>
    dispatch(obtenerProductosAction(busquedaquery, pagequery));

  const cargarCategoria = () =>
    dispatch(obtenerCategoriaActions(busquedaquery));

  useEffect(() => {    
    cargarCategoria(busquedaquery);
    cargarProductos(busquedaquery, pagequery);
    dispatch(obtenerPaginaAction(pagequery));
    console.log("vuelvo a llar a la api");
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [busquedaquery, pagequery]);

  return (
    <Fragment>

      {errores ?        
        <h2 className='col-6 alert alert-warning mx-auto mt-5 text-center'>Inicia Sesión o Registrate</h2>: null}
      <div
        className="container-fluid  my-2 p-1 mt-4"
        style={{ position: "relative" }}
      >
        <div>          
          <div className=" mb-3 col-6 mx-auto">
            <form>
              <div className="container d-flex ">
                <select
                  className="form-select col-6"
                  defaultValue={busquedaquery}
                  name="busqueda"
                  //value={busqueda}
                  onChange={(e) => e.target.value} //SELECCION DE CATEGORIA DE PRODUCTOS A MOSTRAR
                >
                  <option value="all">Ver Últimos los Productos</option>
                  <option value="tabla">Tabla</option>
                  <option value="vela">Vela</option>
                  <option value="botavara">Botavara</option>
                  <option value="mastil">Mastil</option>
                  <option value="accesorio">Accesorio</option>
                </select>
                <button className="btn btn-outline-primary ms-3">Buscar</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            <div>
              <h2 className="mt-5 text-center">Categoria: {busquedaquery}</h2>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row row-cols-2 row-cols-xs-2 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-lg-4 g-3 justify-content-center ">
          {productos === undefined
            ? null
            : productos.map((producto, busqueda) => (
                <Producto
                  key={producto._id}
                  producto={producto}
                  busqueda={busqueda}
                />
              ))}
        </div>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-4 ">
          {paginas.map((pagina) => (
            <Link
              type="submit"
              key={pagina}
              to={`/productos?busqueda=${busquedaquery}&page=${pagina}`}
              className="rounded btn btn-select page-link"
            >
              {pagina + 1}
            </Link>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Productos;
```

I save now in global state the search and the page with redux and then with the reducers i can call in the page that i want the state of the category and the page to return to this page and this category exactly.

**VerProducto.js (component)**

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link} from "react-router-dom";
import "./VerProducto.css";

const VerProducto = () => {    
 
  
  const producto = useSelector((state) => state.productos.productoId);
  const busqueda = useSelector((state) => state.productos.categoria)
  const paginaActual = useSelector((state)=> state.productos.paginaActual)
  console.log(busqueda, paginaActual);

  if (!producto) {
    return null;
  }
  const { title, price, description, images, contacto } = producto;
  
  
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="col">
        <div className="card1 h-100 mt-5">
          <a href={images[0].url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
            <img
              src={images[0].url}
              className="card-img-top1 mt-3"
              alt={images[0].filename}
            ></img>
          </a>
          <div className="card-body">
            <div className="clearfix mb-3 text-center">
              <span className=" price-hp1">Precio: {price} €</span>
            </div>
            <h5 className="card-title titleH5V rounded text-center">{title}</h5>
            <div className="card-header mb-2">
              <span className="card-title pproducto text-center">Descripción:</span>
              <p className="card-title pproducto">{description}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="card-header">
              <span className="card-title  pproducto text-center">Contacto:</span>
              <p className="card-title pproducto ">{contacto}</p>
            </div>
            
            <div className="text-center my-4">
              <Link to={`/productos?busqueda=${busqueda}&page=${paginaActual}`} className="btn btn-outline-success">
                VOLVER A PRODUCTOS
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default VerProducto;
```

If someone wants to see the full code, here is the link to git:
https://github.com/ddaudiosolutions/2nHandMarket-Usuario